# gawk and grep using same pattern but need different treatement for escape sequence

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, gawk

I have a bash shell script (named `testawk` to replace a line containing a pattern (1st arg) with one or more than one line (2nd arg) and operates on the filename given in 3rd arg. The shell script is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  grep -s "$1" "$3"  > /dev/null; then
  gawk -v nm2="$2" -v nm1="$1" '{ if ($0 ~ nm1) print nm2;else print $0}' "$3" > "$3".bak
  mv "$3".bak "$3"
fi
```

If I have a file named "aa" containing the following:

```
a;
b<*c;
```

And, if I run `testawk` as:

```
./testawk "a;" "x<*y;" "aa"
```

aa contains:

```
x<*y;
b<*c;
```

But, if I run `testawk` on original `aa` file again as:

```
./testawk "b<*c;" "x<*y;" "aa"
```

`aa` contains now as (unchanged content):

```
a;
b<*c;
```

Because, `grep "b<*c;" "aa"` cannot find the pattern.
To make `grep` happy, if I use escape sequences as:

```
grep "b<\*c;" "aa"
```

It could match and shows:

```
b<*c;
```

if I use testawk using the escape sequence as below:

```
./testawk "b<\*c;" "x<*y;" "aa"
```

`gawk` does not like that and complains as:

```
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
```

And `aa` gets no changed content as:

```
a;
b<*c;
```

Any remedy to make both `grep` and `gawk` happy to find and replace `b<*c;`
Please suggest how to replace `b<*c;`.

Comment: First, `awk` does pattern matching already, so do you really need to do both?  If you do, try using `-F` for `grep` to tell it to treat the argument as a fixed string, not a pattern

Comment: also, can use `-q` option of `grep` instead of redirecting stdout to somewhere.. it will quit immediately when a match is found, so will be faster as well... and I think `gawk` has an option for inplace editing...

Comment: @EricRenouf just to save time, both grep and gawk used, if the file contains the pattern then gawk is used to go line by line to put as-is or replace if pattern matches

Comment: (@Eric) and to do non-regexp match in `gawk` use `index($0,string)>0` or just `index($0,string)` in a boolean context like `if` instead of `$0 ~ pattern` OP: `grep` goes 'line by line' also, so `grep` plus `gawk` is always more expesnsive than just `gawk`. Although if you want to keep the original file and modtime when no change found, you can have `gawk` return an exit status indicating whether it made a change.

Comment: @Sundeep I think `gawk` 4.1 introduced `-i inplace` as an option, so if it's a recent enough `gawk` that should indeed work

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 in my script, gawk will always return 0 (success), because wither the then part or the else part would work in the if-conditrion, that's why additional grep is used

Comment: by "return 0" I assume you mean "exit with status 0". No, awk will exit with whatever status you want it to exit with. `exit 1` will exit with status `1` for example.

Comment: Can someone suggest the revised script that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what I think you are asking for:

```
if awk -v nm2="$2" -v nm1="$1" 'index($0,nm1){f=1; $0=nm2} 1; END{exit !f}' "$3" > "${3}.bak"
then
    mv "${3}.bak" "$3"
    # do stuff with modified file "$3"
else
    rm -f "${3}.bak"
    # do stuff with unmodified file "$3"
fi
```

No need to escape anything except backslashes and we can deal with that differently if you have those.

Comment: Fine, what changes need to be done if I want only the first occurrence of the pattern to change and retain the rest?

Comment: Stick `!f && ` at the front.

Comment: Got it, if gawk -v nm2="$2" -v nm1="$1" '!f && index($0,nm1){f=1; $0=nm2} 1; END{exit !f}' "$3" > "${3}.bak"